# total times a trigger run in after update event

Tags: process-builder, workflow, before-trigger, after-trigger, order-of-execution

I know that the general order of execution is **trigger > workflow > trigger(if field update) > process**. My question is: we have a trigger, workflow(created every time edited) and process builder(created and every time edited). Considering they all meets the rule/criterions for running:

1. suppose the trigger is **'before insert'** event. Then how many times the trigger will fire? my understanding is for this case the trigger will run 2 times. once before workflow and one time after workflow). Am I right?
2. if the trigger is **'after update'** event. Then how many times the trigger will run? Here also the trigger 2 time same as above. or *will it be 3 times* as it will run after process builder as well?

is my understanding correct?

Comment: Does [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm#!) not provide enough info for you to work this out?

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for the documentation and on going through it many time I have found that the execution order is: 
run all before triggers>save to database> run all after triggers > workflow rules > system validation rules>before update triggers and after update triggers, regardless of the record operation (insert or update), one more time.
If I'm not wrong, then the answer for (1) would be '2' times and for second part it would be '3' times. Right?

Comment: Also, there were many comments from me and other members as well and now they are gone including my comments !! . Is it some page loading error? or something else?

Comment: I can't say what happened to the comments. AFAIK only the original poster of a comment can delete it. Though I guess moderators can too.